# Are there any tools to migrate the interface from legacy GTK applications to a modern GTK Builder based application

Tags: c, gtk, legacy

I'm responsible for a number of legacy C based GTK applications which are starting to show their age. I'm toying with the idea of re-implementing some of them in a more modern framework. Are there any tools which can help migrate a hand-built C based GTK interface into a GTK Builder based XML interface description? My aim would be to separate the interface definition from the actual app implementation.

I suspect it might be possible to ltrace an app and re-build the interface from the GTK library calls but if someone has already solved the problem I'm happy not to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[gtkparasite](http://chipx86.github.com/gtkparasite/) seems to support exporting "live" application UI to GtkBuilder UI files (see http://code.google.com/p/gtkparasite/issues/detail?id=9)

Comment: Good find. Now all I need to do is convert the GtkBuilder XML into old style Glade XML as my Glade is a little too old.

Comment: As far as I remember, Glade-3 can load and save both formats: GtkBuilder and Glade XML.

Comment: It seems the 3.5+ series can and not the version packaged on Ubuntu Hardy LTS. Anyway that's another problem to tackle later on :-)